# Do I get different HH Showcase houses per character?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

For every character (save file), do i get a different "set" of HH Showcase houses?

Also, does Nintendo still give houses via StreetPas/SpotPass? and when?

Thanks.

Comment: Pretty sure they're shared, since only one person can be streetpass-shared person. Haven't confirmed it though.

Comment: so is it possible to choose which character's house will be shared in others' hh showcase? or will it only be the mayor's?

Comment: Yup, you just have to talk to Digby from inside the showcase and it's one of the options.